# How round are filaments?

Tags: filament-quality

I am planning to install a [filament diameter sensor](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4138933) to my printer, but that sensor measures only one diameter. If the filament is not round, an additional error will be introduced.

How round are common filaments? How bad can I expect a filament to be? I mean what are bad values actually measured?

Comment: Haven't you measured it yourself? I can imagine that this depends on manufacturer. I expect premium filament brands to have a tighter quality assurance than non branded or cheap filament brands.

Comment: I can also use my values as reference and hope that future filaments won't be worse than that